# PrimeNG used in shared web component

Tags: angular, primeng, web-component

Is there a way to use primeng in a micro-frontend architecture as a shared lib.
We have a app like bellow

1. shell (/src): Shell loading micro apps
2. client-a (/projects/client-a): Demo micro app

src/app/app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      SidebarComponent,
      NavbarComponent,
      EmptyComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule
   ],
   schemas: [
      CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
```

projects/client-a/src/app/app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'client-a/page1'},
      { 
        path: 'client-a', children: [
          { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
          { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
        ]
      },
      { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
    ], { useHash: true  }),
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Page1Component,
    Page2Component,
    ErrorComponent,
    ClientAWidgetComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  entryComponents: [
    ClientAWidgetComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { 

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const widgetElement = createCustomElement(ClientAWidgetComponent, { injector: this.injector})
    customElements.define('client-a-widget', widgetElement);
  }

}
```

See full example
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-microfrontend

In the above example we can eliminate angular from shared web components and load them only in main app.(Using bellow config)
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-microfrontend/blob/master/projects/client-a/webpack.externals.js

```
module.exports = {
    "externals": {
        "rxjs": "rxjs",
        "@angular/core": "ng.core",
        "@angular/common": "ng.common",
        "@angular/common/http": "ng.common.http",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "ng.platformBrowserDynamic",
        "@angular/compiler": "ng.compiler",
        "@angular/elements": "ng.elements",
        "@angular/router": "ng.router",
        "@angular/forms": "ng.forms"
    }
}
```

Inside angular.json we are using, ngx-build-plus.

```
"builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser"
```

Building web component (client-a) using command. In this way angular in bundled only in shell project not in client-a web component project.

```
ng build --extra-webpack-config webpack.externals.js --prod --project client-a --single-bundle --output-hashing none
```

What about PrimeNG?

Can we do something like above?

PrimeNG will only load/bundle in shell app but shared web components(client-a) will not bundle them.

Comment: Questions with _"Here is a link to my repo, please fix it"_ Usually do not get an answer (as the repo might be gone next week), and in most cases will be closed by SO gurus. Shows us the code that does not run; preferably with a running code snippet you add with the [ < > ] button in the SO editor

Comment: Got it. Same like that example we have to load this file in shell

node_modules/primeng/bundles/primeng-button.umd.js